# Where's umount system call?

Tags: linux-kernel, umount

In the file `util-linux-2.17.2/mount/umount.c`, [line #246](http://pastebin.ca/2460983), it is written `res = umount (node);`.

But where's the `umount` function located? I've searched so much, but didn't find.

Comment: I think umount() is stubbed as a syscall.  The headers seem to indicate that.  Here is what I can find beyond that:  http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/umount.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

umount is a call to the library function of the same name in libc. This function in turn makes a call to the umount system call. How a library function makes a call to the kernel to execute a particular function can be found out by reading about how system calls works. This link might help you in the process [How do system calls work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241627/how-do-system-calls-work)

If you want to know where the system call umount is present, then download the latest kernel. Go to file fs/namespace.c. There you will find

> SYSCALL_DEFINE2(umount, char __user *, name, int, flags)

and

> SYSCALL_DEFINE1(oldumount, char __user *, name)

which define the umount and the oldumount functions.

Answer (score 1):

The `umount` *function* is part of your libc system library. You can find as much using e.g. `objdump -T /lib/libc.so.6 | grep umount`. The `.text` entry in one of the output columns will indicate that that function (and its sibling `umount2`) are defined in that library, as symbols for executable code (as opposed to global variables).

That function is implemented to execute a kernel syscall, usually via a small piece of assembly code. Contrary to most syscalls, glibc doesn't simply include this syscall in its [master list of linux syscalls](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/syscalls.list;h=46205825cae4131f93bc9480f6b961e7878164c6;hb=HEAD). Instead, it has some [dedicated assembly code](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/umount.S;h=e18463e2e6f479388219519c5dddcc09833fd81b;hb=HEAD) in place for this. The meaning of this is hidden behind many layers of macro expansion, and I can't get the preprocessot to emit the final assembly code just now.