# C calling convention: who cleans the stack in variadic functions vs normal functions?

Tags: c, x86, variadic-functions, calling-convention, cdecl

There are some calling conventions (e.g `pascal`, `stdcall`) but as far as I am concerned, C does use `cdecl` (C-declared). Each of these conventions are slightly different in the way the caller loads the parameters onto the stack, respectively which (caller / callee) does the **cleanup**.

Talking about the cleanup, here is my question. I do not understand: are there three different things?

1. stack clean
2. moving the pointer back to the penultimate stack frame
3. stack restoration

Or how should I see them?

Also, the target of this question is basically how could variadic function works in calling conventions like Pascal or `stdcall` where the callee should clear / clean / restore (I don't know which operation) the stack - but he doesn't know how many parameters it will receive.

**EDIT**

Why is it so important the order in which parameters are pushed on to the stack? You still have the first parameter (stable parameter not from ellipsis) which gives you the information about -for example- the number of variable arguments. And there is also the "guardian" which can be added into ellipsis punctuator and can be used as a marker for the variable part's end independent on the calling convention. [In this link](http://csee.umbc.edu/%7Echang/cs313.s02/stack.shtml) why both caller and callee should restore values of those register if they both save their state before messing them up? Shouldn't only one of them (e.g caller) save them on the stack before calling the function and that's all ? Also, on the same link

> "So, the stack pointer ESP might go up and down, but the EBP register
> remains fixed. This is convenient because it means we can always refer
> to the first argument as [EBP + 8] regardless of how much pushing and
> popping is done in the function."

The pushed variables and the local variables are consecutive in memory. Where is the advantage of referring them using the EBP ? They will never have some dynamic offset between them, even if the stack changes in size.

One of the materials I've read is [this site](https://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow2a.html) (only the beginning) for a better understanding on what is exactly the *stack frame*.
Then I went on yt and found these [stack overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dLZRMDcY6c&ab_channel=LuisCeze) and [call stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbZQ-EonR_I&t=13s&ab_channel=LuisCeze) tutorials but they somehow missed the part I needed. [What does exactly happends when you call the function](http://youtu.be/XbZQ-EonR_I?t=361) (I don't understand the instruction "call address" followed by the next instruction `a push` value on to the stack that means the return value). Who controls what the return address will be ? The caller? the callee? When the callee returns, the program contiunes by executing an instruction which is a reading operation from a register or what ?

Comment: restauration == restoration? To answer your question: In the context of returning from a function, all 3 descriptions are essentially the same thing. Note that this question also applies to other contexts, for example, thread context-switching, in which stack restoration is somewhat different.

Comment: Here is one tidbit about MSVC on Windows: [If you try to declare a variadic function with an incompatible calling convention, the compiler secretly converts it to cdecl](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131128-00/?p=2543).

Comment: @dxiv, thanks, very interesting thing. Nice reading

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu Your other comment sounds like something that would better belong into the question, instead. It is not too clear what the wider context of the question is. Once you talk about "stack" you left the C standard realm, and once you get down to stack pointers and frames it's about some particular implementation and/or ABI. Very generally speaking, it *may* be possible in a completely controlled environment for a variadic function to "guess" the number of arguments it was passed, or at least the stack space consumed by them. But that would require a whole lot of fragile assumptions.

Comment: These answers could be helpful: [How exactly does the callstack work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23981943/2455888), [How does a system call work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036382/2455888). If you really want to dig deeper then I would suggest to read Operating System Concepts by Abraham Silberschatz.

Comment: `but he doesn't know how many parameters it will receive` It's completely fine for an ABI to define that compiler needs to pass count of variadic arguments to the function. All these calling conventions are specific to x86, right?

Comment: the reason why I came into this problem is when talking about variadic functions. I was doing the cppinstitute C programming module and they started to speak about this concept ( the ideea was something like "how do you see passing the arguments to the stack, from left to right or from right to left", and then "But the cleaning process, who should be responsable for it?" After all these questions, they jump into variadic functions and let you more confused than you were before starting to read. So I would like just an overview of all this mechanism :), I'm not even thinking about going deeper

Comment: No course on C or C++ should be going into details of how arguments are passed, because neither language specifies, and in practice, the details vary.  Some implementations even provide extensions for declaring different calling conventions to be used for different functions.  If your course nevertheless poses questions about that, then the only reasonable way to answer them is with whatever it presented to you in the course materials.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu; IMHO, stay away from such course, unless you really need cirtification. I would suggest rather grab a good book (suggested book: [C++ Primer](https://www.amazon.com/Primer-5th-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113/ref=pd_sbs_14_1/133-0012890-9758078?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0321714113&pd_rd_r=70e2b7c4-1a64-4006-b4cf-1434d6ab3f6e&pd_rd_w=6ZhoR&pd_rd_wg=CZfTv&pf_rd_p=ff9b5089-1414-4e8f-9675-3397e98bf276&pf_rd_r=MEBSQNEQ1KKGVYRZ7KBP&psc=1&refRID=MEBSQNEQ1KKGVYRZ7KBP)) and follow [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Comment: Hello, I've modified my question after reading all the materials you provided ( not the books, but the articles )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as far as I am concerned, C does use `cdecl`

Its name notwithstanding, the cdecl convention is not universal for C code, not even on the x86 architecture.  It has the advantage of being simple to define and implement, but it makes no use of CPU registers for argument passing, which is more efficient.  That makes a difference even on register-starved x86, but it makes a lot more difference on architectures with more available registers, such as x86_64.

> Talking about the cleanup, here is my question. I do not understand:
> are there three different things?
>
> 1. stack clean
> 2. moving the pointer back to the penultimate stack frame
> 3. stack restoration
>
> Or how should I see them?

I would be inclined to interpret (1) and (3) as different ways of saying the same thing, but it is conceivable that someone would draw distinctions between them.  (3) and related wording is what I encounter most frequently.  (2) is not necessarily the same thing, because there may be *two* relevant stack parameters to be restored: the base of the stack frame (see below), and the top of the stack.  The stack frame base is important in the event that the stack frame contains more information than argument and local variable values, such as the base of the previous stack frame.

> Also, the target of this question is basically how could variadic
> function works in calling conventions like Pascal or stdcall where the
> callee should clear / clean / restore (I don't know which operation)
> the stack - but he doesn't know how many parameters it will receive.

The stack is not necessarily the whole picture.

The callee cannot restore the stack if it does not know how to find the top of its caller's stack, and, if necessary, the base of its caller's stack frame.  But in practice, this is usually hardware assisted.

Taking x86 (for which cdecl was designed) as an example, the CPU has registers for both the stack (frame) base and the current stack pointer.  The caller's stack base is stored on the stack at a known offset (0) from the callee's stack base.  Regardless of the number of arguments, the callee restores the stack by moving the top of the stack to its own stack base, and popping the value there to obtain the caller's stack base.

It is conceivable, however, that there is a calling convention in use somewhere that affords no way to restore the stack to a chosen previous state other than to pop elements one at a time, that does not explicitly convey the number of arguments to the called function, and that requires the callee to restore the caller's stack. Such a calling convention would not support variadic functions.

> Why is it so important the order in which parameters are pushed on to the stack?

The order is *not* important in any general sense, but it is essential for caller and callee, which may be compiled separately, to agree about it.  Otherwise, the callee cannot match the passed values with the parameters they are intended for.  Thus, to whatever extent a calling convention relies on the stack, it must specify precisely which arguments are passed there, and in which order.

Regarding stack frames: this is more material that is not specified by C and that varies, at least to some extent.  Conceptually, though, the stack frame of a function call is the portion of the stack that provides execution context for that call.  It typically supplies storage for local variables, and it may contain additional information, such as a return address and / or the value of the caller's stack frame pointer.  It might also contain other per-function-call information appropriate for the execution environment.  Details are part of the calling convention in use.

Comment: The fact that restoring EBP might make it the caller's frame pointer is basically irrelevant.  Some old systems *required* frame pointers for stack unwinding for debugging, and maybe stuff like C++ exceptions, but that seems like an unnecessary complication to discuss.  Setting up EBP as a frame pointer in your own function and using it as a fixed reference point into your stack frame is something you can do in any calling convention where EBP is call-preserved (all standard ones), without anyone else ever making assumptions about that, or you making assumptions about the caller.

Answer (score 0):

**Note that in practice no mainstream systems ever use callee-pops-args conventions for variadic functions.**  They all use caller-pops, so the callee doesn't need to know the number of args.  It would not be impossible to do callee-pops, but it would generally not be worth the trouble.

For example in 32-bit code for Windows, I think `stdcall` is the default for many Windows DLL functions, but variadic ones use `cdecl`.  (Non-Windows x86 systems like Linux and MacOS typically use caller-pops calling conventions by default, for all functions.  So this really only comes up for 32-bit Windows if we're talking about mainstream systems.)

So `printf` doesn't have to count up the size of args referenced by the format string (or receive a count passed by the caller) and then emulate a `ret 12` or `ret 8` or whatever.  [`ret n`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) is only available in machine code with an immediate operand so you can't do `ret ecx` or something.  It's possible to emulate a variable-count `ret n` various ways, e.g. one of the least bad would be copying the return address higher up on the stack and adjusting ESP before a plain `ret`.  But that's still pretty inefficient compared to just using a caller-pops convention.

Also, that would break some valid C programs: passing an unused arg to `printf` is not UB in ISO C; it's required to be safely ignored.
Some code presumably depends on it being silently ignored.  (By accident or because the types mismatched, or because they always pass some args, but pass a different format string that might print a simpler or more complex output.)

Windows also makes sure caller and callee agree on how much stack space the callee will pop by "decorating" asm symbol names like `_foo@12` for a function like `int foo(int, int, int)`.  (Three `int` args = 12 bytes of stack space for a pure stack-args convention).  So if you declare it wrong (or don't declare it at all, and the implicit declaration uses larger types), you'll get a link error instead of a hard-to-debug error which might only happen in optimized builds.  (If a debug build using EBP as a frame pointer happens to correct for the stack mismatch before anything can go wrong.)

Calling convention mismatch and other asm bugs lead to breakage "below" the C / C++ level, and can be very hard to debug, especially for people that are only looking at C variables in a debugger or with debug-prints.  (Same thing for misuse of GNU C inline asm.)

---

As @johnfound said, the key point with calling conventions is that caller and callee *agree* on the rules.  Any unambiguous set of rules works as long as both parties agree.

Good (efficient) calling conventions (e.g. [x86-64 System V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35619528/224132), and to a lesser extent Windows x64 and 32-bit fastcall/vectorcall) will pass the first few args in registers, avoiding the store/reload to the stack or any stack manipulation for simple functions.  Efficient calling conventions also have a good mix of [call-preserved and call-clobbered registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078). Simple calling conventions pass everything on the stack, with caller or callee responsible for popping the args.   Even simpler ones (like Irvine32 for asm beginners) preserve all the registers.

For good details, see [Agner Fog's calling conventions guide](https://www.agner.org/optimize/).

Comment: Note that in C, you're allowed to pass more args to printf than the format string references. [Stack cleanup in stdcall (callee-pops) for variable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65863892).  So it would be impossible to use stdcall for it, without some hidden extra arg to tell it how much stack-space to pop.  But passing that arg costs at least one instruction, so you might as well just use cdecl instead.